# Alternative method instead of using for f in "$@" bash shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, command, automator

I have the following script that I got from tinypng.com and Instead of using the for f in "$@" command i would like it to just run inside the specified folder on desktop called FOLDER. Thanks!

```
echo ~/Desktop/FOLDER
for f in "$@"
do

   echo $f | while IFS= read file
   do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        ext=$(echo ${filename##*.} | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
        if [ -f $file ]
        then
            if ( [ $ext == "png" ] || [ $ext == "jpg" ] || [ $ext == "jpeg" ] )
            then
                JSON=`curl -i --user api:00000000000000 --data-binary @$file https://api.tinypng.com/shrink 2>/dev/null  `
                URL=${JSON/*url\":\"/}
                URL=${URL/\"*/}

                curl $URL>${file} 2>/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done

done

afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff
```

Comment: Just replace `"$@"` with `~/Desktop/FOLDER/*` then?

Comment: doesn't work. :/. i tried with "" and without.

Comment: why don't you use `optipng` or similar tools ?

Comment: restrictions on the user account I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are simply trying to iterate over files in a folder, than `for f in ~/Desktop/FOLDER/*` should work.

Or alternatively `for f in $(find ~/Desktop/FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f)` 
This one also removes any subfolders from the list so you may get rid of `if [ -f $file ]` (but it also lists hidden files, not sure if that's OK for your case or not)